# Nativescript - ActionBar.navigationButton tap programmatically

Tags: nativescript

At certain point on my app, I´m creating a detail page **programmatically**, but I can´t seem to add a tap action for the page to navigate to the previous one, and I want the button to be on the action bar here is my code:

```
var detailPage = function () {
        var titulo = new labelModule.Label();
        titulo.textWrap = true;
        titulo.cssClass = "titulo";
        titulo.text = tappedItem.titulo;

        var texto = new labelModule.Label();
        texto.textWrap = true;
        texto.cssClass = "texto";
        texto.text = tappedItem.texto;

        var stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        stackLayout.addChild(titulo);
        stackLayout.addChild(texto);

        var scrollView = new scrollViewModule.ScrollView();
        scrollView.content = stackLayout;

        var page = new pagesModule.Page();
        page.actionBar.navigationButton = new actionBarModule.NavigationButton();
        page.actionBar.navigationButton.icon = "res://ic_menu";
        page.actionBar.navigationButton.tap = //??

        page.content = scrollView;
        page.addCss(".titulo {height: auto;margin-top: 10;font-size:13;font-weight: bold;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase}.texto {height:auto;text-align:justify;font-size:11}");
        return page;
    };
```

I don´t know if I´m suppose to use the page.actionBar.navigationButton.tap or if it is done another way...anyone knows how to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event listener can be created with one of the following syntaxes

```
var navButton = new NavigationButton();
navButton.icon = "res://icon";
navButton.on("tap", function() {
    console.log("nav button tapped");
})
// or
navButton.addEventListener("tap", function() {
    console.log("nav button tapped");
});

page.actionBar.navigationButton = navButton;
```